# Jython for Android

Tags: android, jython

I'm testing Jython for Android taken from here http://code.google.com/p/jython-for-android/

Unfortunately I have a problem during the launch... I tried to import
all the libraries in one of my project and in the method onCreate
of my activity I put this code:

```
  PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
  interpreter.exec("print 'hello from Jython!' ");
```

This code should work ( as in the standard java do ) but I get this :

```
Traceback (innermost last):
 (no code object) at line 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader.makeCode(BytecodeLoader.java:104)
      at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1685)
      at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1698)
      at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1706)
      at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:135)
      at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.interact(JythonForAndroidTest.java:29)
```

I have also downloaded the last version from the repo, but nothing changes...
I set the build target to 2.1update...

What could be? Anyone has any experience with this lib?

Thanks in advance ^^

Cheers

Comment: You might have better luck using tinypy and the NDK. I'm sure part of the Java runtime isn't implemented (running new code on the fly) isn't implemented in Android

Comment: It's not what I'm lookin for, but great idea anyway ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you can deal with python instead of jython, Give QPython a try, you can load scripts from your device,whole projects and load from QR codes!  It has a Console and editor too!

I don't currently have a tablet but it will be what I will be using when I do get one.  Currently using it on a Note3.

[Qpython Homepage](http://qpython.com/)

Comment: Answering with language A when all three of the title, body and tag of the question does state the OP uses language B does not make your answer really relevant.